# Вывод куска div в  определенном товаре сайта

Tags: php, smarty

То есть суть такая, есть сайт с разными товарами ИМ (Интернет-магазин). Вот мне надо как-то реализовать, чтобы я мог в определенный товар добавлять див, там уже будет инфа и скрипты. Какой код для этого вывода определенного дива прописать и, как я понял, нужна БД.

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно составлен вопрос, но суть я так понимаю в том что необходима функция добавления информации на сайт (в данном случае информации о товарах). Если так то необходим скрипт который подключается к базе данных и выводит информацию из нее для просмотра, и скрипт для изменения информации в базе данных. Это абстрактно, но если подробнее опишите задачу, смогу набросать скрипт.

Comment: вот скриншот http://s43.radikal.ru/i101/1207/a7/cbbec54fcdfa.jpg компонент интерьера в див заворачиваем,что надо,что я смог допустим в админке к определенной люстре сам добавить этот див со своим светильником а в других либо он не показывался либо не отображался если не стоит,то есть или все через БД делать добавить еще поле а туда код но как сделать что он выводился именно для определенной люстры?

Comment: Поправьте если не так понял. Вы хотите на своем сайте добавить информацию с другого сайта? То есть либо скопировать, либо постоянно отображать участок другого сайта?

Comment: Нет,код будет свой переписать его не проблема,интересует именно как потом код который под свой сайт сделать что отображался определенно для определенного светильника

Comment: Список товаров хранить в базе данных в таблице 1, дополнительные данные к товарам хранить в таблице 2. В таблице 1 указывать какие данные добавлять к товару из таблицы 2, или не указывать. если ничего добавлять не нужно. Скрипт читает базу, и выводит товар и сопоставленную ему дополнительную информацию.